# Akka cluster not binding on the specificied port

Tags: networking, akka, cluster-computing, akka-cluster

i want to configure Akka cluster on 2 machines,  localhost and a remote machine.

i have the following java file

```
public class ShardingApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  startup( );

}

 public static void startup( ) {




  Config remotingConf = ConfigFactory.parseString(
          "  akka.remote {"+
          "    enabled-transports = [\"akka.remote.netty.tcp\"]\n"+
          "    netty.tcp {"+
          "       hostname = \"127.0.0.1\"\n"+
          "       port = "+ 2551+"\n"+
          "       bind-port = "+ 2551+"\n"+
          "     }"+
          " }");

  Config config = remotingConf.withFallback(ConfigFactory.load("application.conf"));




  ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("ShardingSystem", config);

  system.eventStream().setLogLevel(Logging.DebugLevel());

  ActorSystem.create();




  }
 }
```

and this is my Application.conf

```
akka {
   actor {
     provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
 }


cluster {
 seed-nodes = [
  "akka.tcp://ShardingSystem@10.15.70.101:2551"]

# auto downing is NOT safe for production deployments.
# you may want to use it during development, read more about it in the docs.
#auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
   }
}
```

I start this on the remote machine  10.15.70.101   but it bind to port:122248 
Why ?

Comment: TCP and UDP port numbers are a 16-bit value (from `0` to `65535`). Port `122248` is an invalid port number.

Comment: netstat --all --program | grep pid   ...  give me  = 122248

Comment: That is a process ID, not a port number.

Comment: you are right it seems that is not listening on any port.. why ?

Comment: A remote machine cannot reach the localhost on a different machine. Any traffic sent to the localhost will immediately loop back inside the sending host. Any address in the `127.0.0.0/8` block cannot ever be seen on any network, anywhere.